# Safe to use the same instance of shared_preferences in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple question regering the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package in flutter.

Is it safe to get an instance of `SharedPreferences` and store that for future use or is it best to always get a new reference each time?

To clarify, which of these two are the proper or best way of doing it?

```dart
SharedPreferences preferences;

void init() async {
  preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}

void setValue(String key, String value)  async{
  await preferences.setString(key, value);
}
```

```dart
void setValue(String key, String value) async {
  final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preferences.setString(key, value);
}
```

Comment: It's safe to do it either way.

Comment: Even after bringing the app back from the background?

Comment: Yes that doesn't make a difference.